# I have an error when trying to obtain certain statistics (stats) from the PokeAPI using Axios and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, pokeapi

I have a problem, I'm trying to work with the Pokemon API, but when I try to access the attack, HP and speed stats, it shows `undefined` for all the Pokemons! Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my API call?

```
const axios = require('axios');

const apiPokemon = async () => { 
    try {
        const pokemons = await axios
        .get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50')
        const secondUrlMap = await  pokemons.data.results.map(  pokemon  => {
            return pokemon.url
        })
        const pokemonArr = await Promise.all(secondUrlMap.map(async(url) => { 
            const urlResponse = await axios(url)
            return{
                id:urlResponse.data.id,
                name:urlResponse.data.name,
                height:urlResponse.data.height,
                weight:urlResponse.data.weight,
                hp:urlResponse.data.stats.find(stat => stat.name === 'hp')?.base_stat,
                attack:urlResponse.data.stats.find(stat => stat.name === 'attack')?.base_stat, 
                speed:urlResponse.data.stats.find(stat => stat.name === 'speed')?.base_stat,
                types:urlResponse.data.types.map((type) => type.type.name),
                img:urlResponse.data.sprites.other['official-artwork'].front_default,
            }
        }))
        return pokemonArr
    } catch (error) {
        return ({error:error.message})
    }
}

module.exports =  {
    apiPokemon,
}
```

I have an index.js file to test the reception of the API and this is what it returns:

[image: Console output]

```
const { apiPokemon } = require('./apiPokemon')

async function testApi() { 
    const pokemons = await apiPokemon()
    console.log(pokemons)
}

testApi()
```

API structure:
[image: API Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't consider the JSON structure correctly - it's looking for `name` property in the root of each object in array. You need to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to access the `stat` property directly in the condition:

```
hp: urlResponse.data.stats.find(({stat}) => stat.name === 'hp')?.base_stat
attack: urlResponse.data.stats.find(({stat}) => stat.name === 'attack')?.base_stat
// etc.
```

Or you could change `stat.name` to `stat.stat.name`, alternatively.